# Strange update request

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

[image]

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 21.10 a few days ago and checked for updates today. After checking for updates, I got this popup. What does this popup mean?

Comment: I suggest you read the error message. It says "Software updates are no longer provided for Ubuntu 20.10. To stay secure, you should upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04." Are you 100% sure you installed Ubuntu 21.10 and not 20.10.?It looks like you installed 20.10. If you just installed, I advise downloading the Ubuntu 21.10 ISO and reinstalling it. Otherwise, or if you can't for some reason, press the big `Upgrade...` button.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (the October, 2020, non-Long Term Support release) is past its End Of Life date, and is no longer supported. Upgrade to a more recent (or even LTS) release.

Comment: Note that there is no longer a supported upgrade path. Standard releases are supported for 9 months compared to LTS releases which are supported for 5 years. It may be easier and faster to reinstall a supported release. Don't wait until after your release goes EOL to upgrade.  Definitely don't wait so long between package updates!!